# Problem with sqlite_escape_string() In php

Tags: php, sqlite

I have used `sqlite_escape_string()` function in one server and it is working fine.When i use the same code in anther server it throwing an error `Call to undefined function sqlite_escape_string()`I am using PDO for connecting the database.

Comment: I think pdo_sqlite and the sqlite module are two different things. Could you look which extensions you have enabled?

Comment: `sqlite_escape_string(trim($_POST['txt_des))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sqlite_escape_string` is part of the [`SQLite`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) package, which is distincely *different* then the [`PDO_SQLite`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php) package. Go for prepared statements instead of escaping the variables.

Answer (score 12):

```
function sqlite_escape_string( $string ){
    return SQLite3::escapeString($string);
}
```

Comment: It seems as though sqlite_escape_string() is depreciated and no longer used, but many pages refer to it.  This has allowed me to use SQLite3 to escape strings using legacy code.

Comment: this suggestion made me understand the problem.+1

Answer (score 2):

if your php version lower than 5.4 maybe you can use this solution

**if php version < 5.4**

```
if(!function_exists('sqlite_escape_string')){
    function sqlite_escape_string($string) {
        return str_replace("'", "''", $string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sqlite_escape_string()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-escape-string.php) is from [sqlite extension](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlite.php) whereas [pdo_sqlite](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php) is "only" a driver for [PDO](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

You should definitely go for PDO and [prepared statements](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite_escape_string()` is not part of the PDO interface, these are object oriented. Additionally, it is only Sqlite Version 2, while the PDO interface is version 3.

See [Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php) (which specifies that sqlite_pdo *is* necessary if you're on windows).